# P4Python check if file is modified after check-out

Tags: python-2.7, perforce, p4python

I need to check-in the file which is in client workspace. Before check-in i need to verify if the file has been changed. Please tell me how to check this.

Comment: If you don't want to check in un-modified files, run `p4 revert -a` before you submit your changes. `p4 revert -a` will revert those files that are not modified.

Comment: @BryanPendleton I tried this in p4python but failed. What do you mean exactly in p4python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `p4 diff -sr` command.  This will do a diff of opened files and return the names of ones that are unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with in case someone else like me searching for solution

```
if p4.connected():
            p4.tagged = 0
            # Revert all unchanged files
            result = p4.run("revert","-a","-c"+ "23123")

            # Get the number of files after the unchaged files have been reverted
            numofFiles = p4.run("changes", "-l", "23123")

            # Print the result
            print(result)

            # Print the number of files
            print(len(numofFiles))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you can check the creation and modification time of a file

```
import os.path, time
print("Last modified: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getmtime("test.txt")))
print("Created: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getctime("test.txt")))
```

Comment: No one is asking for a modification time here. The OP needs to know if the file changed **relative to the Perforce source control repository**